# Google Sheets Row deletion script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet that I need to have the rows deleted every day. I have found the script but when I try and use it I get an error.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "deleteRows" of undefined. (line 4, file "Code")

And this is the code that I am using:

```
function deleteResponses() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETKEY"); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3]; 
sheet.deleteRows(2, 30);
};
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This line `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3]` assigns `undefined` to `sheet` because your spreadsheet has three or less sheets, as Javascript use 0 based indexes for arrays.

The fix is to change `3` by the proper index number.